# WCF custom ServiceHost on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to host my WCF service with a custom ServiceHost on IIS. I found a couple of articles on MSDN like this: [Custom Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx). Here, I'm supposed to add something to my services svc file, but I don't have one and I can't add one in visual studio either. Then I found this article: [Configuration-Based Activation in IIS and WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This says

"The configuration-based activation feature removes the requirement to have a .svc file and therefore the associated overhead."

so I can just create a `serviceHostingEnvironment` entry in my Web.config (which I don't have either, but I guess App.config is equivalent since it contains my `system.serviceModel` configuration). However, I have to specify a `relativeAddress` for the service activation.

"The relativeAddress attribute must be set to a relative address such as `<sub-directory>/service.svc` or `~/<sub-directory/service.svc`. "

So it should point to my svc file? I'm a bit confused, could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: What's your current project type (windows service?)? But you want to host that service in IIS, don't you?

Comment: I have a WCF service library project and I can host it on IIS I just want to plug my custom ServiHostFactory in

Answer (score 1):

I know documentation on MSDN is little confusing. Here is configuration that you need to put in web.confi/app.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="MyNonExistingServiceSVC.svc" service="MyService" factory=”MyServiceHostFactory”/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Here relative address will be just any dummy name. This name will be used to browse your service metadata. Please note that this name can be anything of your choice and it DOES NOT require same physical file to be present on disk. It just needs any name with .SVC extension.
So while accessing service metadata your URL will be

```
http://myserver/myservice/MyNonExistingServiceSVC.svc
```

Comment: it seems for some reason my ServiceHost factory doesn't get called

Comment: Make sure your service factory name is correct in factory parameter. If it resides in separate assembly other than your service then use assembly name along with type.